# Slicing datasets and store in new dataframes quickly?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and would appreciate your help here.

I imported 4 dataset with the same headers into python. Now I want to create 4 dataframes that contain only selected columns from the 4 datasets. I know how to do it the ugly way but what's the most efficient way to perform this task?

I tried a for loop but couldn't make it work :D

## Datasets imported as df1,df2,df3,df4

```
dataset_list = (df1,df2,df3,df4)
new_dataframes= (df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4)
for i in dataset_list:
    for e in new_dataframes:
        e = i.loc[0:,['column1','column2','column3','column4']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
dataset_list = (df1,df2,df3,df4)
def slice(df):
    return df.loc[:, ['column1','column2','column3','column4']]

df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4 = map(slice, dataset_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
cols = ['column1','column2','column3','column4']
dfs = {k: df[cols] for k, df in enumerate([df1, df2, df3, df4], 1)}
```

The benefit of this method is it caters for an arbitrary number of items without having to manually increment variable names.